# Using CSS, what is the most elegant way to vertical align a short title and a description, not using a table

Tags: css, vertical-alignment

**Not using table** and
**must work in IE 7 and Firefox, Chrome, Safari**

The easiest way to vertically align this:

```
A Title (20px)
With a variable length description (12px), can be 1 line or 2 (when wrapped)
```

inside a `div` that has a width 500px, and height 60px, is probably by using a table.  **Without using a table**, what is the most elegant way to do it?

Please do not simply give a link to a "fixed" height solution as the answer, as this can have variable height.

**Update:** sample and editable test: http://jsfiddle.net/mn2CH/3/

Comment: Do you have an example we can work with?

Comment: sure, and just to see the center effect better, i made the height 100px there: http://jsfiddle.net/mn2CH/3/

Answer (score 2):

Take a look to this:

[Vertical centering with CSS](http://blog.themeforest.net/tutorials/vertical-centering-with-css/)

The Method 2 (using negative margins) is the "classic" approach, I have used it a couple of times.

Comment: Definitely should look at the negative margins approach. Probably the best way I've found as well.

Answer (score 1):

The cleanest approach I've seen that supports older versions of IE is [this method](http://www.jakpsatweb.cz/css/css-vertical-center-solution.html).  Basically, for IE, it uses a clever method of having your main container, in your case it would be 500px by 60px, and then two inner containers - one is positioned relatively with `top: 50%` and the other being relatively positioned with `top: -50%`.  Intuitively, one container is positioned half way down the main container, and then the other container is moved up by half it's own height.

And of course, for newer browsers, you can use the newer `display` attributes on arbitrary elements, which the above article also explains.

Comment: actually... the non-hacked solution won't work in FF or Chrome: http://www.jakpsatweb.cz/css/priklady/vertical-align-valid-solution-en.html  A solution will be better if it is non-hacked for it to be more elegant